# NuGet's Restore Package insists on specific package versions

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I've a project with the following packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Framework.Infrastructure.Core" version="1.4.0.6" />
  <package id="Framework.Infrastructure.Extensions" version="1.4.0.6" />
</packages>
```

Where the Framework.* packages are sitting in our local repository.

I've enabled Package Restore and added our internal repo to the sources. However, when I try restoring the packages from packages.config (which essentially does `nuget install packages.config -sources....`), I get the following errors:

```
error : Unable to find version '1.4.0.6' of package 'Framework.Infrastructure.Extensions'
error : Unable to find version '1.4.0.6' of package 'Framework.Infrastructure.Core'.
```

The repository no longer contains the **1.4.0.6** version of the package (which was relevant a couple of months ago), but rather the new version of it (e.g., **1.5.1.6**).

Why doesn't NuGet find the new versions of the packages? Is there some syntax I can specify in packages.config to ensure that the latest versions will be downloaded?

In short, is there anything short of writing a custom script to update the packages that I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think some people are misunderstanding what Package Restore is meant to do. This feature was added to NuGet solely for the purpose of not requiring packages to be checked into version control. A lot of people were complaining that commiting binaries were exploding the size of their repositories, and is even worse when using a DVCS like git, where the entire repo is downloaded locally and includes every version of package Foo.

So what exactly does Package Restore do? Basically it looks in packages.config of each project and simply pulls down the specific version of the package listed. It's like deleting your packages folder, then doing `git reset --hard` to bring them back (assuming the folder was checked in).

Why is this important? Why not upgrade to the latest package version? If you consider the most common use case of Package Restore, which is to do automated builds, that should give you a clue. The build server should only be building the project that was tested and committed by a developer. If you let the build server decide when to update a package, then you have a project that has not been tested by anyone. As a developer, you should be the one to decide when to do the upgrade.

Remember, installing or updating a package is not simply pulling down a .nupkg file and adding references. A lot of packages have side-effects like updating your .config files, adding code, etc. When you install a package, all of those side-effects happen on your local copy. You can now commit your code and exclude the package files.

When another developer or the build server checks out the code, he'll have the exact same side-effect code you had minus the package files. Package Restore simply pulls these files down from the NuGet repository and now we have everything needed to work on this project.

The NuGet team has promised to maintain all versions of packages so that you will always be able to pull down the correct version. However, as we saw a few months ago, when the NuGet server went down, it pretty much crippled Package Restore and a lot of people were unable to build.

I recommend that you setup your own NuGet repository (a simple file share would do) and keep copies of all packages you use there. This way you are not dependent on an external server for your builds. And as the NuGet team does, you should keep ALL versions of a package. This way if you have to go back and build an older version of your project, you will be sure to have the correct package versions available.

I hope this explains how the feature works and why it works that way.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that you read the [NuGet documentation for Versioning](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning). It explains how version numbers (and ranges) can be utilized in `packages.config` files to allow for the [`Update-Package`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console#Updating_a_Package) command to know what are acceptable versions to upgrade to.

That being said, the Package Restore feature **will not** update packages for you automatically.

With this information, the best workflow IMO is:

- Install the newest, stable version of any new dependency you are adding unless you *really* need an older (or pre-release) version
- Use Package Restore in your CI builds, allowing you to **not** check-in NuGet packages into your VCS
- Only `Update-Package` if...

  - You need a new API call or bug fix from the newest version
  - You have a great test suite for confidence
  - You have time to deal with potential fallout

I do not encourage upgrading packages regularly *just because*. It is better to leave the project working as-is with the older dependencies if they work well enough because there is risk when updating version of any packages.

NuGet packages are supposed to follow [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) which has good rules for allowing the most stress-free package upgrading experience, but because this is not enforced (and trust me, many package publishers don't follow SemVer), you can't rely on it. Even if a package is updated with only a minor version increase, you can't be certain (without sufficient testing) that the new version will work with your code.

In summary, upgrading any packages *automatically* is usually a bad idea. It is better to let the developers explicitly choose with to update any given packages, and only for a good enough reason.

Comment: The problem with it is that based on versioning specification the `version="1.4.0.6"` version (which is by default in packages.config) should be translated into `version >= 1.4.0.6` but it is not. And I think it's a bug in nuget restore because "update" does not use packages.config at all (it's seems it use only folders in `packages` directory - so if you have no packages there "update" won't do anything even if you have packages.config file).

Comment: @FuriCuri The version ranges you describe are only used in `.nuspec` files, not `packages.config`. They are used to describe dependencies between packages. When specifying dependencies in your project, you use the `packages.config` file(s) which will always reference specific version. And yes, you are right, the `Update-Package` command will not work unless you have recently built your project and all the NuGet dependencies are present in the `/packages` directory. This may be inconvenient or unintuitive but I don't believe it is a bug; it is simply the way the NuGet operates.

Comment: I see. Well, I've described it here https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3264 The biggest problem is that if you try to nuget restore project and have some package referenced with an old version that is no longer available in repository (but there is a newer version) there is no way to make nuget update versions in packages.config and .proj file for that package.

Comment: @FuriCuri I think you are conflating the idea of package restore and updating packages. Originally, NuGet didn't even have package restore; you had to commit the contents of your `/packages` dir into version control. They introduced package restore to allow users to avoid this. If you are in the scenario where packages are being removed from your local repo, as your issue describes, you may want to consider not using package restore. Don't fight the framework.

Comment: Very subtle points in the discussion. I was wondering why range isn't working via pakages.config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply remove and re-install the packages from nuget, the version property will refer to the latest version.

You may well need to edit the packages.config manually to remove the old reference before re-installing from nuget (as I had a situation recently where nuget wouldn't allow me to install the new package as it thought I had the old package present)

Comment: Yes, it does, but the OP mentioned if there was any packages syntax config to get the latest versions. Once this has been done once, anyone else using the repository will be able to grab the project using package restore

Comment: The project in question is a part of a custom solution template I'm doing for our internal projects. The idea is that a developer would create a new solution from the template and get the entire structure (including ready references to out Infrastructure packages) in place and ready to go. I have no problem writing a custom script that would go over all the projects in the solution and re-install the packages as needed, but telling people to start mucking around in a template to have it working is wrong...

Comment: In any case, I find it **very** odd that NuGet wouldn't try to fetch the latest package from the repository.

Comment: Personally I would have expected nuget NOT to get the latest package, reason being it could introduce bugs into your software which one developer may experience and another not. 
Last time I used package restore it was to ensure I was using a specific version of a package to ensure we didn't create a discrepancy in the team or force people to get new packages each time the opened the project.

Comment: The point of package restore is to restore packages, not update them.  A nuget compatible work flow would be to keep the old packages so nuget can restore them, then run update.

Comment: @ilyawur If you have a solution template that includes NuGet packages, I would include a README file that explains what packages are included, and add a reminder that the developer can run `Update-Package` to get the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, I wrote a PowerShell module and wrapped it in a NuGet package that users need to run upon template creation. The script goes over each C# project in the solution, locates its "packages.config" (if any), then removes and re-installs each package mentioned there.

Clearly, there's much room for improvement, both in terms of the general approach and in terms of small bugs (for instance, the nuget command in the install section will not run on solutions which have spaces in the full name), but this is a start.

File **NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects.psm1**

```
$NuGetSources = "https://nuget.org/api/v2/;" # put your internal sources here as needed

function NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects {
    # get the solution directory
    $solutionDir = (get-childitem $dte.Solution.FullName).DirectoryName

    # for each C# project in the solution, process packages.config file, if there is one
    $dte.Solution.Projects | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "C#" } | ForEach-Object {
        $currentProject = $_
        $currentProjectName = $currentProject.ProjectName
        $currentProjectDir = (get-childitem $_.FullName).DirectoryName

        Write-Host ******* Starting processing $currentProjectName

        # get the packages.config file for the current project
        $packagesFile = $currentProject.ProjectItems | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "packages.config" }

        # if there's no packages.config, print a message and continue to the next project
        if ($packagesFile -eq $null -or $packagesFile.count -gt 1) { 
            write-host ------- Project $currentProjectName doesn''t have packages.config
            return 
        }

        # read the contents of packages.config file and extract the list of packages in it
        $fileName = $currentProjectDir + "\packages.config"
        [xml]$content = Get-Content $fileName
        $packageList = $content.packages.package | % { $_.id }

        # for each package in the packages.config, uninstall the package (or simply remove the line from the file, if the uninstall fails)
        $packageList | ForEach-Object {
            $currentPackage = $_

            write-host Uninstalling $currentPackage from $currentProjectName

            try {
                Uninstall-Package $currentPackage -ProjectName $currentProjectName -RemoveDependencies -Force
            }
            catch {
                write-host '!!!!!!! $_.Exception.Message is' $_.Exception.Message
                $node = $content.SelectSingleNode("//package[@id='$currentPackage']")
                [Void]$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
                $content.Save($fileName)
            }
        }

        # download each package into the $(SolutionDir)packages folder, and install it into the current project from there
        $packageList | ForEach-Object {
            $currentPackage = $_
            $localPackagesDir = $solutionDir + "\packages"
            $cmd = $solutionDir + "\.nuget\nuget.exe install " + $currentPackage + " -Source """ + $NuGetSources +  """ -o " + $localPackagesDir

            write-host Installing $currentPackage to $currentProjectName
            invoke-expression -command $cmd
            Install-Package $currentPackage -ProjectName $currentProjectName -Source $localPackagesDir
        }

        Write-Host ******* Finished processing $currentProjectName
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects
```

File **init.ps1**

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)

Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects.psm1)

Enable-PackageRestore

NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects
```

The **.nuspec** file for the package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects</id>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <title>Custom NuGet Package Restore</title>
        <authors>Me (c) 2012</authors>
        <owners />
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Restore all packages in a given solution from packages.config in each project. For each packages.config, uninstalls all packages and then re-install them again from the sources specified in the script.</description>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="NuGetPowerTools" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="init.ps1" target="tools\init.ps1" />
        <file src="NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects.psm1" target="tools\NuGet-RestorePackagesInAllProjects.psm1" />
    </files>
</package>
```