# nuget restore fails on build but works manually

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

VS 2013 fails to restore a package - the package contents are not materialized - although VS/nuget appears to think that it did restore the package successfully.

If I manually uninstall and re-install the same version of that package, it works as it should.

A bare-bones repro can be [downloaded as a zip](http://www.ideablade.com/friends/NugetRestoreFail.zip). This repro has a

- single solution with a
- single project with a
- single file, "packages.config", specifying a
- single package, "breeze.edmbuilder -version 1.0.4", containing a single file, *edmbuilder.cs*
- single folder, "App_Start", contains nothing but
- the .csproj says it should have "edmbuilder.cs" which is ok because
- it WILL have "edmbuilder.cs" when the package is restored.

When I build, VS reports that "edmbuilder.cs" is missing ... and indeed it is missing.

However, the package was downloaded; I know this because the build produces a "packages" folder that contains "Breeze.EdmBuilder.1.0.4" wherein I see that "edmbuilder.cs" is present and in the right place.

When I issue the command `install-package breeze.edmbuilder -version 1.0.4`, nuget reports

> *'Breeze.EdmBuilder 1.0.4' already installed. NugetRestoreFail already has a reference to 'Breeze.EdmBuilder 1.0.4'.*

There is nothing wrong with this package AFAIK. For when I `uninstall-package breeze.edmbuilder` and then reinstall with `install-package breeze.edmbuilder -version 1.0.4`, the install works and the missing *edmbuilder.cs* appears in the "App_Start" folder where it belongs.

The failure is repeatable *in place*.

- close the solution
- delete *edmbuilder.cs* from "App_Start"
- delete the "packages" folder
- optionally delete the .suo and bin and obj directories
- re-open the solution and re-build

You'll get the same failing behavior ... and the same ability to manually uninstall and reinstall.

FWIW, removing the reference to *edmbuilder.cs* from the .csproj has no effect.

No matter what I do, I have to manually uninstall and re-install the package.

**WTF!**

p.s.: I am using VS 2013 Update 2 RC. I doubt that the "RC" matters as this problem came to my attention from a customer. You never know.

p.p.s: This is not about the build failing and I don't care that this solution would never run. What you see here is a stripped down version of a real app that would have worked. The only question is "why no restored file?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package Restore is **NOT** the same as installing a package. What you are seeing is by design. It simply downloads any missing packages in the *packages* folder. No more. No less.

Package Restore was added so you wouldn't need to commit the packages folder to source control.

It is expected that you would install a package then commit the changes made to your project files as well as any files that may have been added like your *edmbuilder.cs*, essentially anything inside your project folder. You would exclude the packages folder.

Now when you get the source from source control everything would be present except for the package files. Package Restore would download those and now your working copy is complete.

See [NuGet's Restore Package insists on specific package versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630414/nugets-restore-package-insists-on-specific-package-versions/11633139#11633139)

Comment: Hold on. I read your link and it seems to say that restore will have the same side-effects (" like updating your .config files, **adding code**, etc.") as the install. It goes on to say "When another developer or the build server checks out the code, he'll have the **exact same side-effect code you had minus the package files**. Package Restore simply pulls these files down from the NuGet repository and now we have everything needed to work on this project." That is pretty confusing. You're saying restore will NOT have the install side-effects?

Comment: Actually what I wrote is that *installing* a package is what introduces the side-effects. It is this *minus* the actual packages that are committed. Package Restore simply *adds* the packages back making your working copy whole again. And yes I agree that this is a byproduct of the VS project system. However NuGet packages aren't simply assemblies to reference. They may also include install scripts which may not work outside the context of VS such as a build server. If you simply think of Package Restore as saving you from checking in packages it'll make more sense.

Comment: Here's a blog post that calls this out as a common misconception:
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/12/09/nuget-package-restore-misconceptions.aspx

Content files added into a project must be checked in with the project.  Pretend they didn't come from NuGet.  They are now editable source files in your project.

Binaries were the reason why package restore was created--nobody wants to check 3rd party binaries into source control.

Answer (score 1):

## Is this stupid or what?

Thanks to @Kiliman for explaining that my horrible experience is "by design".

So how do you actually get the content you thought was being restored? Do you install each package one at a time. That's insane.

I was going to observe that there is no nuget equivalent of an `npm install` that would fetch all the packages you need ... when I discovered that there actually IS an almost-equivalent. It's just not obvious and I wonder how many people know it exists.

It's a two step process:

1. FIRST restore the missing packages ... THEN
2. Issue the command: `Update-Package -Reinstall`

This re-installs all packages in every project in your solution.

If you only want to re-install for a specific project, try:

```
Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectName' -Reinstall
```

In both procedures, the `-Reinstall` switch strives to install the exact versions of the packages spelled out in your package.config ... and not newer "updated" packages which may or may not work for your project (but see the documentation for exceptions).

Read about `update-package -reinstall` in the official nuget documentation entitled, "[**Reinstalling Packages and its Pitfalls**](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages)".

**Do not miss the cautionary remarks**. Clearly this technique is but an approximation of what you'd expect from other package managers.

Good luck, peoples.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but I'm not sure I see the problem. How are you specifying the packages if you didn't *install* them in the first place? This gives you everything you need to restore successfully. I think other package systems are simpler because the underlying platform's build systems are simpler. I know there is a push to improve the VS project system. Hopefully they take this scenario into consideration.

Comment: Thanks @Killman. I appreciate your help and kindness while regretting my own petulance. Just because nuget is a consistent thorn in my  side is no reason to take it out on you. I should add that the other package managers come with their own frustrations. Apparently the problem is hard. I will strive to be more gracious and understanding in future.